# best replacement for eval() in AS2 calculation

Tags: flash, actionscript, eval, actionscript-2

I got a simple calculator script and I have to replace the `var a = eval(tmp);` with something that works. For example `var tmp` could be filled with `4+5`. In plain JS this should work and output a `9`, but here in AS2 it won't. `trace(a)` outputs `undefined`. What should I change, to get it to work.
Is there a similar command, like in JS?

Here the complete ActionScript:

look for the `BtnCalc.onPress = function(){}`

```
var calcArr = new Array();

Btn0.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = 0;
}

Btn1.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = 1;
}

Btn2.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = 2;
}

Btn3.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = 3;
}

Btn4.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = 4;
}

Btn5.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = 5;
}

Btn6.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = 6;
}

Btn7.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = 7;
}

Btn8.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = 8;
}

Btn9.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = 9;
}

BtnCalc.onPress = function() {
    var tmp;
    for (var i = 0;i<calcArr.length;i++){
        if (i>=1){
            tmp = tmp+calcArr[i];
        }else{
            tmp = calcArr[i];
        }
        trace(tmp);
    }
    var a = eval(tmp);
    trace(a);
}

BtnAdd.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = "+";
}

BtnSubtract.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = "-";
}

BtnMult.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = "*";
}

BtnDivide.onPress = function() {
    calcArr[calcArr.length] = "/";
}
```

Comment: why are you still using actionscript 2? actionscript 3 performs much better

Comment: sorry friend I could have helped you, but Actionscript 2 is no longer supported by any adobe products. I can give you alternative script if you like in actionscript 3

Comment: because we only work with Macromedia Flash 8 in our school :/

Comment: ok thats a legacy. anyway lets see what I can do. but honestly, I can only give you untested suggestions. I don't have Macromedia Flash 8 to test anymore.

Comment: If you can suggest a solution, your welcome. I will test it, tomorrow in my class, and post the result.

Comment: I am sorry to say that there is no any function in actionscript 2 to work as javascript eval(). BTW you should change the way you are coding. How about capturing digit press as number and only do calculation when any of  the arithmetic operation keys are pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = "+", m = "*", s = "-", d = "/", D = ".", e = "=";
_global.lastOperator = "+";
label.text = this._name.split("_")[1];
if (eval(label.text) != undefined) {
    label.text = eval(label.text);
}
_global.a = 0;
_global.b = 0;
this.onPress = function() {
    switch (label.text) {
    case "C" :
        _global.a = 0;
        _global.b = 0;
        _global.lastOperator = "+";
        trace2(_global.b);
        break;
    case "=" :
        calc();
        _global.b = _global.a;
        _global.a=0;
        _global.lastOperator = "+";
        break;
    case "+" :
        calc();
        _global.lastOperator = "+";
        break;
    case "-" :
        calc();
        _global.lastOperator = "-";
        break;
    case "*" :
        calc();
        _global.lastOperator = "*";
        break;
    case "/" :
        calc();
        _global.lastOperator = "/";
        break;
    default :
        _global.b = _global.b+""+label.text;
        trace2(parseFloat(_global.b));
        break;
    }
};
function trace2(msg) {
    _root.op.text = msg;
}
function calc() {
    switch (_global.lastOperator) {
    case "+" :
        _global.a += parseFloat(_global.b);
        trace2(_global.a);
        break;
    case "-" :
        _global.a -= parseFloat(_global.b);
        trace2(_global.a);
        break;
    case "*" :
        _global.a *= parseFloat(_global.b);
        trace2(_global.a);
        break;
    case "/" :
        _global.a /= parseFloat(_global.b);
        trace2(_global.a);
        break;
    }
    _global.b=0;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no `eval()` alternative in actionscript 2. So you should change whole coding pattern into something like this.

Create a movieclip with a dynamic textarea named "label" and paste above code on first frame of the movieclip using action panel.

Now you can create multiple instances of same movieclip and name them as

"btn_0",

"btn_1",

"btn_2",

...,

"btn_9",

"btn_p",

"btn_m",

"btn_s",

"btn_d",

"btn_D",

"btn_e"

After buttons, create a dynamic text area named "op" at the root of the stage.

Thats it, and you got your calculator.

Also, have a look at line number 4 to see proper use of as2 `eval()`.

**I strongly advise not to use actionscript 2 because it is obsolete.**

Finished code can be downloaded from my [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_AKfmXEaZvQNnhtekYyRkxXTDA/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: [Picture-Link](https://picload.org/image/wdggwll/untitled.png) here is a screenshoot, that I edited for you. Can you spot a mistake. It Output a ´undefined´ in the label text-field
I named all Buttons-Instanzes new, to btn_0....
It is the german programm-layout, but it should be similar to the english.

Comment: Looks like you are mistaken at above line: 
Create a movieclip with a dynamic textarea named "label"

Comment: Create a movieclip and place a dynamic textarea inside it with name "label"

Comment: How about downloading finished .fla file from given link and check what you are doing wrong.

Comment: can you pls reupp your *.fla-file, I end up at a 404-Site

Comment: I put the label-text into a new movieclip, but now no output anymore. I would love to compare with your *.fla-file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_AKfmXEaZvQNnhtekYyRkxXTDA/view?usp=sharing link works

Answer (score 0):

It can be better if you detect which button pushed in listener function instead.

Comment: For example if it is grid when each cell is button you can find button from mouse pointer coordinates.